# How to handle View State in Android development in the right way

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata, android-architecture-components

Currently I've this approach in my app:

**ViewState**(one viewState to each screen)

```
sealed class CategoriesViewState {
    object Loading : CategoriesViewState()

    data class Error(
        val errorMessage: String,
        val messageType: UIComponentType
    ) : CategoriesViewState()

    data class CategoryList(
        val categories: List<Category>
    ) : CategoriesViewState()
}
```

And I observe this state in my fragments/activites using live data:

```
  viewModel.viewState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            when (it) {
                is CategoriesViewState.Loading -> {
                progress_bar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                    Log.d(TAG, "LOADING")
                }

                is CategoriesViewState.Error -> {
                progress_bar.visibility = View.GONE

                    Log.d(TAG, "ERROR")

                }

                is CategoriesViewState.CategoryList -> {
                progress_bar.visibility = View.GONE

                    Log.d(TAG, "DATA")

                }
            }
        })
```

And it is working fine.

**BUT** it seems to me inefficient as the app grows.

Let's say I've 20 screens in my app: I'll need 20 viewStates, I'll need to write the same when statement in every screen, I'll need to write this ugly Visible/Gone in every screen(not to mention I need to set Loading state in every call)

Maybe I'm totally wrong and it's common approach, But to me it seems like **A LOT** of code duplication.

I haven't a specific question, I Just wanna know if it is common approach in Android Development and if not, what am I doing wrong in my code?

Comment: Your question seems too broad to me, but I know the exact solution that you need. You need to create an abstract activity and fragment that all your other pages (Activity/Fragments) would eventually inherit. For your States on every page, I'll post answer to that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Regarding your states for different activites, you don't need to make it every time you make new screen. You can follow approach like below and modify accordingly:

```
sealed class UIState<out T> where T : Any? {

    object Loading : UIState<Nothing>()

    data class Success<T>(val data: T) : UIState<T>()

    data class Failure(val errorMessage: String, val messageType: UIComponentType) : UIState<Nothing>()
}
```

So, now your `CategoriesViewState` can be represented as `UiState<List<Category>>`.

I'd also created some extension functions to make things easier on observe:

```
infix fun <T> UIState<T>.takeIfSuccess(onSuccess: UIState.Success<T>.() -> Unit): UIState<T> {
    return when (this) {
        is UIState.Success -> {
            onSuccess(this)
            this
        }
        else -> {
            this
        }
    }
}

infix fun <T> UIState<T>.takeIfError(onError: UIState.Failure.() -> Unit): UIState<T> {
    return when (this) {
        is UIState.Failure -> {
            onError(this)
            this
        }
        else -> {
            this
        }
    }
}
```

And during observe method of live data:

```
viewModel.viewState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { state ->
    state takeIfSuccess {
        // Here's the success state
    } takeIfError {
        // Here's the error state
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

If you don’t want to end up writing diamond brackets (`<>`), here's the way to use type alias;

```
// for UIState of UserData class you can do something like this,
typealias UserDataState = UIState<UserData>
...

// Then use this typealias where you should be writing UIState, I.e.
val userLiveData = MutableLiveData<UserDataState>(value)
```

Comment: Awesome. Do you have some example project you use this?

Comment: @pantos27 Classes I shared above are generic, so you can put them in your project & then let's say you have to display list of items on one activity, your viewState would look like this: `UIState<List<Products>>`

Comment: One thing to note here is I hate diamond braces while typing generics so I use type alias in kotlin, you can do the same.

Comment: @JeelVankhede 
"I use type alias in kotlin, you can do the same" 
Can you please share how to do this?

Comment: @WebServices Done! Edited my answer if you can check.